# PHP CURL which only autofills form but not autosubmit

Tags: php, curl

I am new to CURL, my requirement is to login to a Portal and submit a form. So far, my CURL code logs in to the portal, but when it comes to the form, I don't want it to **submit/post** the form for now.. so that I can see what strings are being passed to the form's `<input>` fields.

The code below `autofill` and `autosubmit` the form, but I want only **autofill** the form for now.

```
<?php
$data=array();
$data['usr']='username';
$data['pswd']='password';
$post_str=' ';
foreach($data as $key=> $value){
$post_str.=$key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; 
}
$post_str=substr($post_str,0,-1);
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://benefit.blue-ex.com/customerportal/");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str); $response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: I can't see any forms here.

Comment: The form that is being called is only the login form for now.. http://benefit.blue-ex.com/customerportal/

Comment: Do you want to get results of `javascript` related to the form you want to fill?

Comment: For now I want to see what data is being filled in the fields..
I just don't want to "trigger" the form submission.